# Scheduled file transfer via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

For the scheduled part I will use Quartz.net but for the file transferring part I am completely lost.

I found many examples but not close to what I need. I want to use two WCF libraries (no graphical interface) hosted in IIS to transfer files, no more than one GB. I understand the code (most of it) but when it comes to the ABC (address, bindings, contracts) it gets complicated. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: George, seems you are afraid to try to do the transfer. Related on the nature of the files transfer you either use IO or Web API. There are a tonns of examples on Stackoverflow. Just make your goal clear and go ahead. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! To make my goal clear I need to know my available options but I don't! What do you mean "you either use IO or Web API" ? How do I combine that with WCF?

Comment: WCF is a foundation that helps to "talk" between client and server. The file transfer routine you want to provide is a business functionality that your service should implement. What "makes" it "WCF" is just a service contract that lets the service clients to trigger the functionality on the service server. The transfer code itself is just a code that can be executed in a simple Console application.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a powerful framework and flexible in terms of IPC. And that flexibility has accompanied of complexity as well ( may be for me when I was learning this stuff ).

1. Address - Where is the service? It pertains to the location of your service just like URL.

> Ex. http://localhost/YourServicePath/Service.svc

2. Binding - How do I talk to the service? This is quiet complicated because it involve protocols and security. Binding defines on how both client and server will communicate to each other. There are different types of bindings. Bindings can be done through configuration file and/or programmatically.

> Ex. BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding ,WSDualHttpBinding ,
>   NetTcpBinding, WSFederationHttpBinding, NetNamedPipeBinding,
>   NetMsmqBinding,NetPeerTcpBinding

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wshttpbind"  allowCookies="true" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
        receiveTimeout="00:01:00" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

3. Contracts - What can the service do for me? Contracts are all information exposed to both party that agrees to used for exchanging of message. It could be Data, Operation/Service/Methods or Message contract.

> Ex. Service Contract, DataContract, Message Contract and Fault
>   Contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculate
{
   [OperationContract]
   double Add( double a, double b);
   [OperationContract]
   double Subtract( double a, double b);
}
```

I suggest to you to read [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731067%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about it first for you not to lost along your development.